# Should "/branches/x" folders on SVN be deleted after being fixed?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

On default SVN's, there are three directories:

**Trunk:** This stuff works, but hasn't been released

**Branches:** Buggy, may not include all changes

**Tags:** Released versions, never directly edited

### **My question:**

Now, after branches are "fixed" and merged into trunk as needed, are they deleted, or are they left to rot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete it.  A delete in svn doesn't remove it from history - If you want it back you can always revert the commit that deleted it.

The biggest reason is that after a reintegrate merge the branch is unusable. From the [redbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html)

> Once a --reintegrate merge is done from branch to trunk, the branch is no longer usable for further work. It's not able to correctly absorb new trunk changes, nor can it be properly reintegrated to trunk again. For this reason, if you want to keep working on your feature branch, we recommend destroying it and then re-creating it from the trunk

[Further interesting reading](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/subversion-merg)

It's better to keep things clean, even if you're not using the `--reintegrate` it always sucks when you have to scroll through the list of branches.

Odds are you'll not need to restore it, since you can examine all the files and history without restoring it.

Comment: hmmm... both links seem to be working, though the collab.net one is quite slow.